# How do I make a question that if answered wrong gives you another chance?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script based story inspired by Black Mirror: Bandersnatch. This is my first time using Python or any other scripting programs so I'm REALLY bad. This is what I wrote:

```
  print("Hello! I'm your personal A.I. ")
q1 = input("Are you sure you want to begin this journey? (yes/no)")
if not q1 == "yes":
    print("Okay. Have a nice day")
    exit()
if q1 == "yes":
    print("You have chosen to begin this journey. Do not be sure you will make it to the end.")
    from time import sleep
    sleep(5)
    print(

    )
    print("You are in an old house. It's dark. You look around.")
c1 = ("There is a dirty window to your left. "
      )
c2 = ("In front of you there is a door. Light is coming from underneath."
      )
c3 = ("There is also a staircase to your right."
      )
q2 = input("Which one do you choose to go to? (window/door/staircase)")
if q2 == "window":
    print("You go over to the window. You try to look out but you can't see anything."
          )
    print("You go back")
```

This is where I need help. I need to return to c1 and start over the question. How do I do this?

Comment: Hint - while loop https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: Read about looping with `while` in whatever learning material you're using.

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It will repeat your question until you input something else instead, in this case, 'window'.
Just write logic for other options.

```
while True:
    q2 = input("Which one do you choose to go to? (window/door/staircase)")
    if q2 == "window":
        print("You go over to the window. You try to look out but you can't see anything."
          )
        print("You go back")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

when comes to `continue` it will proceed again from start of the while loop. And...when it comes to `break`, it will go out from the loop. simple as that